# How to push or upload projects from different folders in one Solution to Github in visual studio 2019?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2019

I have a Solution with original project: Lab_01_ConsoleAppMike. Then in the Solution I added another existing project from different folder: Form_Lab_Mike. And I pushed the Solution to the [Github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlUUR.jpg). It just pushed just one project: Lab_01_ConsoleAppMike that located in original project folder. The other project from different folder: Form_Lab_Mike did not load to git.

My question is: How to push or upload projects from different folders in one Solution to Github in visual studio 2019?

Here some photos of this problem:
[Github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlUUR.jpg)
[Did not load Form_Lab_Mike to the Github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QM3B.jpg)

Comment: Thank everybody for the answers, i am new here, so just appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git repository handles files that are located in the same folder (like solution root)

Please ensure that both projects `Lab_01_ConsoleAppMike` and `Form_Lab_Mike` are in the one folder and add the `Form_Lab_Mike` using `git add Form_Lab_Mike` command.

There is an `submodule` [git feature](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) that can reference to another repository and have files from another repository.
However this may work if you have `Form_Lab_Mike` project uploaded to git hosting already.

You may add submodule using `git submodule add  <repositoryurl>` if you have `Form_Lab_Mike` hosted by git already.

Comment: Yes, Thank you oleksa, moving the other project to the original project's folder and changing the path for the second project helped.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Thank you oleksa, moving the other project to the original project's folder and changing the path for the second project helped.

Here is how I did it:

1. Copy the second project folder to the original project's folder:

[second project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3z41Q.jpg)
and
[copy to original project's folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5W30.jpg)

2. Add existing Item. Choose the second project folder  that is already in original project's folder.

[Add existing Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41mK4.jpg)